# Is prior knowledge of OpenGL or OpenGL ES needed to learn WebGL?

Tags: webgl

Is it necessary to know OpenGL or OpenGL ES to proceed with WebGL?

Answer (score 0):

No, prior OpenGL knowledge isn't strictly required to learn WebGL.

Start here: http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217

Answer (score 0):

Only in as much as webgl is very similar to modern opengl in many ways so if you learn one you'll be learning most of the other...